# How to draw 1 pixel long dotted lines in DirectX?

Tags: directx, hlsl

How can I draw lines similar to the negative axis in Google Sketchup ?
I know I can parametrize the line using texture coordinates and draw the line in homogenous coordinates.
But if my pixel shader has some logic like tex.u%5<1, surely sometimes I'll get 2 pixel dashes or 0 pixel dashes.
How exactly would I get exactly 1 pixel dashes every say 5 pixels like in the screenshot ?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styled and pattern lines are best drawn using Direct2D. With DirectX 11.1 or later, interop is quite easy.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370966.aspx)

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the right thing to do actually. Thanks!

Comment: Although, using Direct2D will make it less easy to draw it using the zbuffer ? Or I guess, I draw it to a texture using Direct2D and draw that using the zbuffer. That should work nicely. Just thinking out loud, hopefully this can help someone.